# How to add addtional permissions on facebook

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps

How to add more permissions when the uses have accessed my app permissions of my app?
I have specified some permissions when i first publish my app on facebook. Some day later, I find our need extra permissions to add.how to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Using [`FB.ui`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui/) and `permissions.request`, you can do something like this:

```
FB.ui({
   method: 'permissions.request',
   'perms': 'read_stream',
   'display': 'iframe'
  },
  function(response) {
     //callback
  }
);
```

Or, you can use [`FB.login`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/):

```
FB.login(function(response) {

        if(response.authResponse) {
          //Logged in
        } else {

        }

}, {scope: 'email,user_birthday'});
```